# CompletableFuture with Runnable-delegation - exception is ignored in delegating class

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I am facing an issue while converting my code to non-blocking code using CompletableFuture. To minimize the scope of the question, I created a [sample code](https://github.com/PatelVishalJ/CompletableFutureTest) which behaves differently when I use CompletableFuture. The issue is CompletableFuture swallows the exception from Runnable-delegation.

I am using delegation on top of Runnable and ExecutorService to provide some wrapper code required in my original application.

Sample code:

- MyRunnable: My sample runnable, which always throws the exception.

  ```
  public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

      @Override
      public void run() {
          System.out.println("This is My Thread throwing exception : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
          throw new RuntimeException("Runtime exception from MyThread");
      }
  }
  ```
- DelegatingRunnable - this is delegating runnable which delegates and wrap logic around the Runnable passed to it, and placeholder for the exception handling.

  ```
  public class DelegatingRunnable implements Runnable {

      private Runnable delegate; 

      public DelegatingRunnable(Runnable delegate) {
          this.delegate = delegate;
      }

      @Override
      public void run() {
          System.out.println("Delegating Thread start : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
          try {
              // Some code before thread execution
              delegate.run();
              // Some code after thread execution
          } catch (Exception e) {
              // While using CompletableFuture, could not catch exception here
              System.out.println("###### Delegating Thread Exception Caught : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
              //throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
          } catch (Throwable t) {
              System.out.println("!!!!!!! Delegating Thread Throwable Caught : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
          }
          System.out.println("Delegating Thread ends : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
      }

  }
  ```
- DelegatingExecutorService - this delegates execute method. It just wraps the runnable with DelegatingRunnable.

  ```
  public class DelegatingExecutorService extends AbstractExecutorService {

      private ExecutorService executor;

      public DelegatingExecutorService(ExecutorService executor) {
          this.executor = executor;
      }

      @Override
      public void execute(Runnable command) {
          executor.execute(new DelegatingRunnable(command));
      }

      // Othere delegating methods

  }
  ```
- MainClass - I am using two approaches. Way1 - using ExecutorService without CompletableFuture. Way2 - using CompletableFuture

  ```
  public class MainClass {

      public static void main(String[] arg) {
          //way1();
          way2();
      }

      public static void way2() {
          System.out.println("Way:2 # This is main class : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

          ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()+1);
          DelegatingExecutorService executorService = new DelegatingExecutorService(executor);

          CompletableFuture.runAsync(new MyRunnable(), executorService)
              .whenComplete((res, ex) -> {
                  if (ex != null) {
                      System.out.println("whenComplete - exception  : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                  } else {
                      System.out.println("whenComplete - success  : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                  }
              });

          executor.shutdown();
          System.out.println("main class completed : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
      }

      public static void way1() {
          System.out.println("Way:1 # This is main class : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
          ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()+1);

          DelegatingExecutorService executorService = new DelegatingExecutorService(executor);

          executorService.execute(new MyRunnable());

          executor.shutdown();
          System.out.println("main class completed : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
      }
  }
  ```

**Question:**
When I run way1(), the output is

```
    Way:1 # This is main class : main
    Delegating Thread start : pool-1-thread-1
    This is My Thread throwing exception : pool-1-thread-1
    ###### Delegating Thread Exception Caught : pool-1-thread-1
    main class completed : main
    Delegating Thread ends : pool-1-thread-1
```

You can notice that catch block of 'DelegatingRunnable' can catch the exception here, which is raised from MyRunnable. But if I use way2() using CompletableFuture, the exception from MyRunnable is not cought under DelegatingRunnable, though I see it is being cough under 'whenComplete' callback of CompletableFuture.

Output of way2 is

```
    Way:2 # This is main class : main
    Delegating Thread start : pool-1-thread-1
    This is My Thread throwing exception : pool-1-thread-1
    Delegating Thread ends : pool-1-thread-1
    whenComplete - exception  : main
    main class completed : main
```

You can notice that the CompletableFuture is using the same DelegatingExecutionService and DelegatingRunnable internally. I do not understand why DelegatingRunnable cannot catch the exception in this case.

(Why I am using CompletableFuture? - This is just a sample code to explain the exact issue I am facing. But overall, I need to use CompletableFuture to make chain of task evantually in non-blocking way)

Comment: My guess is that the CompletableFuture is not calling your execute() method in DelegatingExecutorService - so you never get a chance to wrap your DelegatingRunnable around the given Runnable...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the source code of `CompletableFuture` you can see that it wraps the given `Runnable` in an object of type `AsyncRun` which itself implements `Runnable`.
This `AsyncRun` will be passed to your executor's `execute` method.
When the inner/original `Runnable` throws an exception, it gets caught by the code of `AsyncRun` and the `CompletableFuture` is completed as failed but the exception will *not* get re-thrown.

That's why your wrapper (`DelegatingRunnable`) will never see the exception.

Comment: As an addition, you will get into the same kind of problem when you use `submit` instead of `execute` in `way1()`…